# Adding doubles appending instead of summing

Tags: c#

I am working on a calculator and whenever my calculator adds up a number it just joins them together.

An example of this is 3+5 it gives me 35. I converted the numbers into doubles and it still gives me 35. Here is my code:

```
Console.Write("Enter a Number: ");
double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Enter a Operator: ");
string op = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("Enter a Number: ");
double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

if (op == "+")
{
    Console.WriteLine(num1 + " plus " + num2 + " is " + num1 + num2);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Thank you for viewing my post have a nice day.

Comment: Side note - try `Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2 + " is result of " + num1 + " plus " + num2);` - may help understanding the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there are strings involved in your expression using `+`, and because of the order in which those string arguments appear in that expression, the C# compiler treats the `+` operators as string concatenation.

In more detail: The `+` are interpreted as string concatenation because the expression is evaluated from left to right. The first evaluated term is `num1 +  " plus "`. Since there is a string involved, the first `+` is treated as operator for string concatenation. With the first term evaluated to a string, the second and following `+` each with their respective second argument are then also treated as string concatenation, because the left-hand side of each (partial) term is always being evaluated to a string.

A "cheap" way to fix the code is to use parantheses to help the compiler to distinguish between the arithmetic operator and the string concatenation operator:

```
Console.WriteLine(num1 + " plus " + num2 + " is " + ( num1 + num2 ) );
```

A safer and more readable way to write the output can be achieved by using string interpolation (note the `$` symbol in front of the string), which conveniently gets rid of the `+` operator confusion:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{num1} plus {num2} is {num1 + num2}");
```

(Thanks to @AlexeiLevenkov for pointing out the latter)

Comment: Also your answer is a bit misleading (less then DeanOC's one) too "there are strings involved" is not enough - `Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2 + " is result of " + num1 + " plus " + num2);` is very similar but produces perfectly correct results... Operator precedence and associativity for the win.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are sufficient and explain the problem, though you might like to use [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), and [`double.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) to validate the input and give feedback on failure

[String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

> The $ special character identifies a string literal as an interpolated
>   string. An interpolated string is a string literal that might contain
>   interpolated expressions. When an interpolated string is resolved to a
>   result string, items with interpolated expressions are replaced by the
>   string representations of the expression results. This feature is
>   available in C# 6 and later versions of the language.

[Double.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Converts the string representation of a number to its double-precision
>   floating-point number equivalent. A return value indicates whether the
>   conversion succeeded or failed.

**Example**

```
// valid operators
var ops = new[] { "+", "-", "/", "*" };

double num1;
Console.Write("Enter a Number: ");
while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num1))
   Console.Write("Invalid number, try again");

string op;
Console.Write($"Enter operator (\"+\", \"-\", \"/\", \"*\"): ");
while (!ops.Contains(op = Console.ReadLine()))
   Console.Write("Invalid operator, try again");

double num2;
Console.Write("Enter a Number: ");
while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num2))
   Console.Write("Invalid number, try again");

// local function to do stuff
double ApplyOperator()
{
   switch (op)
   {
      case "+": return num1 + num2;
      case "-": return num1 - num2;
      case "/": return num1 / num2;
      case "*": return num1 * num2;
      default: throw new InvalidOperationException();
   }
}

// an interpolated string
Console.WriteLine($"{num1} {op} {num2} = {ApplyOperator()}");

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output**

```
Enter a Number: 1
Enter operator ("+", "-", "/", "*"): +
Enter a Number: 2
1 + 2 = 3
```